# How to keep notes when learning R?

Tags: r

I am  currently self learning R and I would like to know what is the best way to keep notes. I am currently using Microsoft Word which is not that great. Ideally, it will be great if the software has the following features:

- An index so that I can quickly refer to the code easily .
- Highlights the code similar to Rstudio
- Able to save text as well as R plots.

Are there any software that can do that ? Further, what are some tips and best practices when self learning R  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply, keep your R history with your comments. Then you can copy and paste them to any editor for further edit and search. More advanced way is using sweave or R Markdown but first you should learn them.

Answer (score 6):

[R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) is a great way to create pretty documents with integrated R code. RStudio, the most popular IDE for R, makes creating them completely effortless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) you can use [Sweave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave). [Knitr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knitr) is another (maybe even easier) option

Answer (score 0):

I have found it useful to create R scripts for each topic I study.  I have one for general R functions, one for regex, one for XPath, one for ggplot, etc.  In them I use one of my data frames and simply apply each function or technique against that data frame (adding to it as I find the need for some extra content).  I can comment what I learn from the training and easily modify the code to learn arguments, syntax, etc.

With that set of learning scripts plus my actual coding scripts, I make frequent use of RStudio's Edit/Find in Files to see previous examples of code for a given function.

I also keep Word files that correspond to the R scripts and copy what I find on Stack Overflow to be useful into it.  Those files use the Table of Contents feature of Word to keep order.